# Angular/RxJS - Correct way to emit values after Promises resolve?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using a HTTP library that uses promises. I want to emit a value to a data steam after all of the promises resolve. I need it to be an observable because I want to update data in a table upon calling a trigger.

The code "works". It waits for all streams to complete before running the function and emitting a new observable. I can also make a new HTTP call and update the data.

```js
 ngOnInit() {

    //Turn call from Promises into observables
    this.assignmentWaivers$ = from(this.dataService.fetchAllAssignmentWaivers(this.courseId));
    this.evaluationWaivers$ = from(this.dataService.fetchAllEvaluationWaivers(this.courseId));
    this.redlines$ = from(this.dataService.fetchAllRedlines(this.courseId));

    //Instead of this call being an observable make it a subject so the value can be reemmited. 
    this.dataService.fetchAllSubmissions(this.courseId).then(data => this.submissionsSubject.next(data));

    this.awardModel$ = from(this.dataService.FetchAwardModel(this.courseId));
    this.stratResults$ = from(this.dataService.fetchAllStratResults(this.courseId));
    this.workGroup$ = from(this.dataService.fetchAllGroups(this.courseId));
    this.course$ = this.route.data.pipe(pluck("course"));

    this.gradeData$ = combineLatest([this.submissionsSubject, this.stratResults$, this.course$, this.workGroup$, this.awardModel$])
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
        tap(value => console.log('It triggered the combine latest')),
        tap(value => console.log(value)),
        map(value => this.createGradeData(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4]))
      );
  }
```

Update the data in the table

```js
trigger() {
    this.dataService.fetchAllSubmissions(this.courseId).then(data => this.submissionsSubject.next(data));
  }
```

Clean up

```js
 ngOnDestroy() {
    //Clean up the drop subscription to prevent errors.
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    this.submissionsSubject.complete();
  }
```

Again this is "working" but are there any unwanted side effects I might be missing? Is this the best way?

This line in particular seems hacky...

```js
    this.dataService.fetchAllSubmissions(this.courseId).then(data => this.submissionsSubject.next(data));
```

Comment: Why can't you directly `from()` to convert the promise to an observable ?

Comment: I can but why is converting it to a observable and subscribing better than a promise? When both need to wait for completion to do the  this.submissionsSubject.next(data)?

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the promise to resolve before `this.submissionsSubject.next(data)`, what do you want to do? The question doesn't seem to clear for me

Comment: I guess based on the response there is nothing wrong with it. I just haven't mixed promises and observable like that before and was doubting my solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from`

```
from(this.dataService.fetchAllSubmissions(this.courseId)).subscribe(data => this.submissionsSubject.next(data))
```